# Dynamically created ahref click event not working in firefox or safari?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari

i am creating ahref tag dynamically using javascript to download csv file generated using javascript code. The following code is working fine in chrome but doesn't work in safari or firefox...

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var blob = new Blob([str], {'type':'application\/octet-stream'});
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = 'export.csv';
a.click();
```

any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

To make it work in Firefox, just insert the new element into the DOM (`apendChild`, etc).

I don't think this will work in Safari:

- `<a download="">` isn't (properly) supported yet, AFAIK. E.g. `a.download =` will not do what you want. You could still use `setAttribute` but Safari will still ignore it.
- I don't think Safari does support downloading of blob:-URIs, anyway.