# Triggering a click event in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, csv, onclick

My requirement is to import a html table to a CSV file. The code below gets called when the Download to CSV button is clicked in my web page. This works fine in chrome however in firefox it does nothing.

```
input.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var fileName = cntrySel.value + '-Data.csv';
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var data=$('#output').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
    blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' }); //new way
    var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.href = csvUrl;
    a.click();
    a.setAttribute('onClick','');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

In firefox debugger, I can see the above function is getting triggered upon click but a.click() does nothing in FF whereas it downloads the csv file in chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soon after I posted this question, I came across this link [Dynamically created ahref click event not working in firefox or safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303695/dynamically-created-ahref-click-event-not-working-in-firefox-or-safari?rq=1) which has the answer.